# JQuery: события готовности страницы, помогите разобраться

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Привет, прошу прощения за избитый вопрос, но всё же столкнулся с проблемой:

Всегда вешал весь фронтэнд на `$(document).ready(function(){ /* js */ });` и всё работало прекрасно, но тут столкнулся с проблемой определения высоты у колонок в при помощи `$('#element').height();` и я заметил что высота определяется по разному. Иногда до применения стилей css (!sic), иногда после применения css. (стили подключаются в хедере до jQuery). Собственно сами вопросы:

**1)** Когда срабатывает `$(document).ready`, на готовность только DOM дерева без применения стилей? как в таком случае ведут себя "инлайн стили" без css типа `<p class="super__padding" style="padding: 100px 50px;"></p>` ?

**2)** Когда срабатывает `$(window).load`? Как я понимаю когда загрузятся все объекты включая всю графику <img />?, включена ли сюда графика css `background-image: url();`? а если она прописана "инлайн" в теге style=""? Включен ли сюда "кроссдомен"? (имею ввиду фреймы шаринга соцсетей, гугл аналитикс и тд)

**3)** Мне нужно определить некие "визуальный" параметры у некоторых элементов, такие как (width, height) учитывая загруженные стили и шрифты, но не хотелось бы ждать window.load как поступить?

P.S> CSS имеет несколько загружаемых шрифтов что также вливает на размер и высоту блоков.
Уверен информация будет полезна всем!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $(document).ready реагирует на полное построение только DOM дерева, при этом инлайн-стили применяются сразу во время построения, в отличие от внешних стилей. Этот способ не ожидает загрузку внешних стилей, картинок, содержимого фреймов и т.д.

2) $(window).load ожидает загрузку всего: картинки, внешние стили, фреймы и т.д. При этом учитываются все элементы, которые могут как-то повлиять на разметку и только после этого срабатывает. Я так понимаю это требование должно ожидать и загрузку background-image: url().

3) Такие способы мне не известны.

Answer (score 1):

По пункту 3:
Событие onload можно биндить не только на body, но и на некоторые другие элементы, в т.ч. на img, link, style. Размеры картинок можно определять на сервере и указывать в атрибутах img.

Есть плагин для отслеживания загрузки картинок внутри элемента: http://www.cirkuit.net/projects/jquery/onImagesLoad/

Загрузку шрифта отследить скорее всего не получится. Но можно повесить обработчик на таймер, который будет работать до $(window).load.